# Taking all duplicate values in column as single value in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My current dataframe is:

```
     Name   term    Grade
  0    A      1       35
  1    A      2       40
  2    B      1       50
  3    B      2       45
```

I want to get a dataframe as:

```
     Name   term    Grade
  0   A      1        35
             2        40
  1   B      1        50
             2        45
```

Is i possible to get like my expected output?If yes,How can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for boolean mask with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['Name'].duplicated()
#more general
#mask = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated()
df['Name'] = np.where(mask, '', df['Name'])
print (df)
  Name  term  Grade
0    A     1     35
1          2     40
2    B     1     50
3          2     45
```

Difference between masks is possible seen in changed `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
  Name  term  Grade
0    A     1     35
1    A     2     40
2    B     1     50
3    B     2     45
4    A     4     43
5    A     3     46
```

If multiple same consecutive groups like 2 `A` groups need general solution:

```
mask = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated()
df['Name'] = np.where(mask, '', df['Name'])
print (df)
  Name  term  Grade
0    A     1     35
1          2     40
2    B     1     50
3          2     45
4    A     4     43
5          3     46
```

---

```
mask = df['Name'].duplicated()
df['Name'] = np.where(mask, '', df['Name'])
print (df)
  Name  term  Grade
0    A     1     35
1          2     40
2    B     1     50
3          2     45
4          4     43
5          3     46
```

Comment: I'm just curious... any reason you're choosing the mask/np.where approach here instead of something like: `df.loc[df.Name.duplicated(), 'Name'] = ''` ?